# How can I keep selected two different select options on same page an get their values

Tags: php

Can someone explain to me how can I set two select options selected, and also get their values.

So far I have this:

php

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select class="custom-select-sm" id="inputGroupSelect01" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" onchange="window.location='?htid='+this.value" name="selHomeTeam">
<option value="-1">Choose...</option>
<?php 
$teams = Team::getAll();
foreach ($teams as $team) {
echo "<option " . ($selectedHomeTeam->team_id == $team->team_id?"selected":"") . " value='{$team->team_id}'>{$team->name}</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</div></td>
<td>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
</div>
<select class="custom-select-sm" id="inputGroupSelect01" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" onchange="window.location='?atid='+this.value" name="selAwayTeam">
<option value="-1">Choose...</option>
<?php 
 $teams = Team::getAll();
foreach ($teams as $team) {
echo "<option " . ($selectedAwayTeam->team_id == $team->team_id?"selected":"") . " value='{$team->team_id}'>{$team->name}</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<?php 

if (isset($_GET['htid'])) {
  $selectedHomeTeam = Team::getById($_GET['htid']);
} else {
  $selectedHomeTeam = new Team;
  $selectedHomeTeam->team_id = null;
}  if (isset($_GET['atid'])) {
  $selectedAwayTeam = Team::getById($_GET['atid']);
} else {
  $selectedAwayTeam = new Team;
 $selectedAwayTeam->team_id = null;
}
```

If I click on first select option, I get his value, but if I click on second select option, first one is lost.
What I want is to keep both values selected and get their values, something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit the form instead of changing the window location.
Add id to your form first

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
```

And when you are changing the select box value, submit the form like,

```
onchange="$('#myForm').submit()"
```

For both the select boxes.

if you are using POST as form method then values of the selected drop down in your request array will be like,

```
$_POST['selAwayTeam']
$_POST['selHomeTeam']
```

Comment: but also I'm intrested how can I send values with `$_GET` to get `...php?id=2&something=3`

Comment: @aks then maybe spend a moment to think about what `method="POST"` on the form element could possibly mean.